# Is there a way in Team Foundation Server 2008 to limit who can start a build by user?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, tfs

I have two build definitions in TFS, one for QA and one for Production. I would like to make it so that developers can deploy to QA, but so that only my IT Admin can run the Production deploy. It doesn't have to be locked down, but more of a safety guard so I don't mis-click or accidentally kick off a production deploy.

Ideally it would be nice to link this to the windows user, but I am open to other suggestions if it still meets the needs.

Comment: Which version?  Build control between '05, '08, and '10 are radically different

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I wasn't sure. In my case we are currently VS2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control who can queue a build.  But once someone has rights to start a build they can start any build.  So if you had a QA Build and a Prod build you could give rights to both or neither, but not one or the other.

These rights are controlled by right clicking on a project in Team Explorer and selecting **Team Project Settings** and then **Security** or **Group Membership**.

**Edit:** You could change the permissions on the build definition in source control to not allow the restricted user to see the build definition file for the prod build.  This was discussed on this [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/124bd266-6b6c-41fb-9181-ccd344aa90e1/).  I am not 100% sure that would work, but it could prevent accidents.